# How to run unity game on browser?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have made a game with **unity** and I would like to share it with my friends but not sure can they play it on browser, is it even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Build your game as `WebGL`. **File**->**Build Settings**-> Select **WebGL** then click the **Build** button. It will be build the project for web. Now you can host the file in your server and the game is now accessible to others.